# How to fetch data between two dates from access in java?

Tags: java, sql

```
String weeklyQuery = "Select ItemName, SUM(Unit) As SoldUnit, SUM(Total) As
                      TotalAmount, SUM(Profit) As TotalProfit 
                      from InvoiceTable 
                      Where DateSO BETWEEN?AND?GROUPBY ItemName"
```

By using this query no exception or error occrus bt result not generated means not a single record fetched.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're trying to make the query to database in a **very strange way**.
Actually, it's **never done like this** in java.

What you need to do:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                     "jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",
                     username,
                     password);

PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "Select ItemName
          , SUM(Unit) As SoldUnit
          , SUM(Total) As TotalAmount
          , SUM(Profit) As TotalProfit 
       from InvoiceTable 
      Where DateSO BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUPBY ItemName");

pstmt.setDate(1, dateSOMin);
pstmt.setDate(2, dateSOMax);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    String itemName = rs.getString("ItemName");
    int soldUnit= rs.getInt("SoldUnit");
    int totalAmount= rs.getInt("TotalAmount");
    float totalProfit = rs.getFloat("TotalProfit");

    //do something with it
}
```

Also, are sure your database sql dialect allows you to write `BETWEEN min AND max`?

Probably your database will only permit you to write `where DateSO >= min AND DateSO <= max`

**I suggest you reading this tutorial:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For lack of information I will throw in a suggestion.

Change the between clause to DateSo > smallestDateYouWant And DateSo < largestDateYouWant

Also, attach a sample set so we may test without going in blind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The query statement you have written is fine. But you might try like this:

```
String weeklyQuery = "Select ItemName, SUM(Unit) As SoldUnit, SUM(Total) As
                      TotalAmount, SUM(Profit) As TotalProfit 
                      from InvoiceTable 
                      WHERE DateSO >= ? AND DateSO <= ? GROUPBY ItemName"
```